# Problems with Google Earth

Tags: 12.04, login, skype, google-earth

How to put in a normal font in Google Earth and correcting bugs logging in?

I use 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my notebook, Lenovo N500.
I tried the methods from this site and the site www.omgubuntu.co.uk. All methods have failed.

Besides the ugly fonts I can not log into Skype or to log into my Google account in Google Earth. For Skype, not to worry because I do not use it much, and I have it on Windows 8 Consumer Preview and on my Android smartphone, LG Optimus 2X. But Google Earth for Android is not available in my country. Given that I use Ubuntu more than Windows this represents a problem to me.

What should I do?

Comment: What methods have you tried?

Comment: I tried metods from various sites dedicated Ubuntu fans.

Comment: But *what* (exactly) have you tried? How do I know what not to suggest?

Comment: I tried the method for Ubuntu 11.10 from the site www.omgubuntu.com, because there are no methods for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: @legospace9876 - there is a step by step guide here - does it work for you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/41562/how-to-fix-fonts-in-google-earth-6

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try this, if you haven't already: http://omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/how-to-make-google-earth-look-native-in-ubuntu

Comment: This method does not work because I have no authority for editing sistem files in Gedit.

Comment: Skip that part, and just install the libfreeimage3 package from Ubuntu, instead of downloading the random binary file from the Internet.

Comment: to use Gedit with Super User privileges, hit alt+f2 and type gksudo gedit -> then enter your password. HTH

Comment: It works 3 secs and Google Earth is closed.

Comment: Sounds like perhaps Google Earth is crashing for some reason then. You'll have to find out where and why it's doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Install a linux version of microsoft fonts. Check it out here http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/google-earth-62-released-with-new-way.html

Comment: It works 5 secs. and bye Google Earth.