# Google Earth Font Problem

Tags: 12.04, fonts, google-earth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix fonts in Google Earth 6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41562/how-to-fix-fonts-in-google-earth-6)

I installed Google Earth 64 bit in Ubuntu 12.04, and the fonts look ugly, no surprise there.
I went through the process of installing the ttf-mscorefonts-installer, it looks better but still not right.

Any idea how to fix this?
I cant post a image how the fonts look like now, unfortunately, i am a newby.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me though

Comment: not so sure this is a duplicate since this may be an issue with 64 bit google earth on 12.04 specifically. As for me the 11.10 supposed answeres ruined my google earth install and I had to reinstall. Now looking for a 12.04 answer